# change value of list in python

Tags: python

I found this code in harris corner detector at opencv library

```
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
```

where `img` is a list which represent the image and `dst` is a list which result from the libary,

can anyone describe what the meaning from that code?

Comment: "where img is a list" No it's not.

Comment: I don't know the specifics but break it down... `img[ dst>0.01*dst.max() ] = [0,0,255]`. `img` is "something" that supports indexing since you can use `[]` - presumably it's a `list`. @Goyo, care to elaborate? Everything within the first sets of `[]` will determine *where* the stuff on the right sign of the `=` gets placed within `img`. Indexing only works with integers so we know that the result of `dst>0.01*dst.max()` must be an integer. I don't know which datatype `dst` is (is it a class, maybe?) but if you write `type(dst)` and `dir(dst)` python will show you its datatypes and methods.

Comment: @jDo You said: `dst>0.01*dst.max()` must be an integer, of course it might be but I bet it's not (never seen a class implementing `<` that way). Also I do not think opencv is using python lists for image processing.

Comment: @Goyo No, I think you're right. OpenCV will be using something more efficient since it's dealing with some pretty heavy calculations. The other answers seem to be more informed and they agree with you. I was just "disassembling a UFO" (i.e. taking the naive approach to figuring stuff out when you have absolutely no idea what you're looking at).

Comment: img is numpy array, sorry i miss about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's a numpy array, not a list. This is logical indexing. The `>` comparison returns an array of booleans. Wherever those are `True`, the corresponding element of `img` is set to `[0, 0, 255]`. More directly, it's creating a ring of blue points, where the radius of the inner empty circle is 1% of the maximum of `dst`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess, it makes a blue circle.

The right hand side seems to be ab RGB-value, the img is a 2D-Array of pixels, and dst sounds like distance. So there is a circle with radius of 0.01 times the maximal distance.